# Customized View

Tags: views, entities, uri

I am a beginner in Drupal, I am creating "view" for content type and i want to customize it as follows;

- Title background to be colored (shaded)
- Read More (which leads to original content path)

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

For the title, you will need to style it by applying CSS to the appropriate class. See, for instance: https://www.drupal.org/node/2083339

The "Read More" link can be configured through the "More link", in the "Pager" section:

[image: Views - More link]